How to clone boot partition in another drive and make it bootable?
I am running Debian 12 on my system with two drives of same storage. The root and swap partition are in RAID-1, but I did not do the same for the boot partition since I thought the contents are same in every boot partition. Now, the system is booting from boot partition in /dev/sda1, I want to have a backup boot partition in /dev/sdb1. I tried to clone the contents of /dev/sda1 to /dev/sdb1 using dd, but it did not work. I have also tried running grub-install /dev/sdb1 which did not work.
The other drive won't show up in UEFI boot selection. How do I create a bootable partition /dev/sdb1 in case /dev/sda1 ever fails?

You need to tell the UEFI firmware of your computer that there is a bootloader on that partition! efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdb (not sdb1!) would do that.
However, questionable whether you really want that – you'd have indistinguishable "duplicate" entries. If you just remove /sda (e.g., because it failed), the firmware should look for potential candidates to boot from – at the very least, you should be able to select a bootable drive at boot (typical key: F12).
Caveat: secureboot's whole point is to make sure nobody goes, plugs a hard drive/nvme/USB stick with an EFI partition on it in your PC, and boots it, completely bypassing any security your system has against unauthorized access. Typical firmware might, when secureboot is enabled, not allow you to just select a new boot drive, even if that contains a signed bootloader (because the bootloader is bit-wise identical to the original). This will depend on the firmware.
